# Equivalent of C# 'as' command in C++?

Tags: c++

In C# you can use `as` to convert a type or get null:

```
Object o = Whatever();
String s = o as String;
```

Is there a similar easy way to achieve this in C++?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, if that's important.

[Update]: Remember, there is a very important difference between casting and using `as`. Casting (at least in C#) will throw an exception if the type does not match:

```
Object o = null;
String s = (String)o; // Will crash.
```

Comment: None of the answers suggesting using `dynamic_cast` are correct.  The C# keyword is a conversion operation, but `dynamic_cast` is a cast.

Comment: @Jon Dibling - 'as' is a cast. it only succeeds if the cast is valid.

Comment: @sylvanaar:  According to the C# spec, the cast operator and the `as` keyword both perform conversions.  See 7.9.11 and 7.6.6

Comment: @John, they might technically not be 100% identical, but this was 100% what I was looking for, and it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, this would be a dynamic_cast, if you had a hierarchy where Object is the parent and String is the child.

```
Object * p = createMyObject();
String * s = dynamic_cast<String *>(p);
if(s)
{
  ...
}
```

Dynamic casting a pointer will return a pointer to the object if the cast is possible, or a null pointer if not.

Also, dynamic casting a reference will return a reference to the object if the cast is possible, or throw an exception.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. should be: `dynamic_cast<String*>(p);` and you should note that String must be derived from Object.

Comment: As an extension to what Neil said, there is no common base class that all classes in C++ automatically derive from. Some libraries do have such a central class, like Qt and wxWidgets, but these are explicitly derived from, either directly or through another class.

Comment: C#'s `as` keyword is a conversion, not a cast.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ there is no base object class, so in general there is no way of doing this. You can however do it for specific hierarchies:

```
struct A {
   virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : public A {
};

A * p = Something();     // Something() may return an A * or a B *
B & b = dynamic_cast <B&>(*p);
```

The dynamic cast will throw an exception if p does not point at something that can safely be converted to a B reference.

Comment: just to confirm, can we dynamic_cast on reference?

Comment: We should note the differences of casting a reference to casting a pointer. If the dynamic_cast fails: on a pointer then NULL is returned; on a reference an exception is thrown

Answer (score 3):

Use [`dynamic_cast<type>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/), but it will only work with pointers, not static objects.

Comment: With pointers, you get a null pointer if the cast is invalid. It works with references, but throws an exception if invalid.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read from: [C# Programmer's Reference: AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28VS.71%29.aspx) the as operator performs the same task as [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast) in C++.

Comment: No, it most definitely does not.  C#'s `as` is a conversion.  dynamic_cast is a cast.

Comment: Considering this from the c# programmer's reference: *The as operator is like a cast except that it yields null on conversion failure instead of raising an exception.* And: `expression as type` is equivalent to: `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`. I'd say the `as` operator is most resembling the `dynamic_cast` especially since `as` cannot perform user-defined conversions.

Comment: I understand this, but the question is about an equivalent operation in C++, so even though it is not important to distinguish between 'cast' and 'convert' in a language like C#, there is a big difference in C++. So it is important to be clear.  You said yourself, "as is like a cast" -- not "as *is* as cast." And the C# spec is equally explicit: (7.6.6) : "A cast-expression is used to explicitly convert an expression to a given type" and (7.9.11) : "The as operator is used to explicitly convert a value to a given reference type or nullable type"  These are conversions, not casts.

Comment: An interesting note on the `as` keyword from the [MSDN: C# for C++ Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28VS.80%29.aspx): *The as keyword is similar to a standard cast, except that rather than throw an exception if the conversion fails, the return value is null. This is similar to using static_cast in C++, which, unlike dynamic_cast, performs no run-time check and hence does not throw an exception on failure.*

Answer (score -1):

In C# the `as` keyword **converts** a value to another type.  There is code that supports this conversion (probably in the C# runtime).  This is not a cast.

For the most part you can't use `dynamic_cast` or any other kind of cast in C++ to accomplish this, because casts and conversions are not the same thing.  I say 'for the most part' because some types can be *converted* using `static_cast`, to convert an `int` to a `float` but this is still a conversion, not a cast.  Also, if you have introduced a type system where everything is derived from an `Object`-like base class that has this conversion functionality, you might be able to construct a mechanism to support this conversion using `dynamic_cast`, but you would have had to write this mechanism and this does not seem to be what you're trying to do.

There is nothing built-in to C++ which will do this conversion for you; in other words, there is no C++ equivalent to the C# `as` keyword.

If you want to perform this conversion, you can often use streams:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float f = 42.0f;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << f;
    string s = ss.str();
    cout << "Float: " << f << ", String '" << s << "'";

    return 0;
}
```

`<sstream>` is part of the C++ Standard, so in this regard you might consider it to be 'in the language'.

Using streams to do this conversion can be rather clumsy.  [Boost offers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) `lexical_cast` which can be used to perform these simple conversions with less code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "42";
    float f = boost::lexical_cast<float>(s);

    cout << "Float: " << f << ", String '" << s << "'";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between casting and converting a reference type in c#?

Comment: @sylvanaar:  In C# there seems to be no such thing as a true 'cast' in the C++ sense.  In C++ a cast means "pretend variable x is of type Y", but according to the C# spec, (7.6.6) "A cast-expression is used to explicitly convert an expression to a given type." and (7.9.11) "The as operator is used to explicitly convert a value to a given reference type or nullable type. Unlike a cast expression (§7.6.6), the as operator never throws an exception. Instead, if the indicated conversion is not possible, the resulting value is null."

Comment: @sylvanaar:  If you downvoted my answer, you must think it is wrong.  What, exactly, is wrong in my post?

Comment: Why is using As on a reference type in c# not the same as using dynamic_cast on a pointer in C++? MS does mix their terms a little but the c# spec says "The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception" I don't think you are correct in drawing such a strong distinction between cast/convert in this instance. But ill remove my downvote - just edit your post

Comment: @sylvanaar: The downvote isn't the issue.  The correctness of `as` being a cast is what I'm taking issue with here.  The spec is explicit: (7.6.6) : "A cast-expression is used to explicitly convert an expression to a given type" and (7.9.11) : "The as operator is used to explicitly convert a value to a given reference type or nullable type" These are conversions, not casts.

Comment: Maybe its a confusion about what is being converted ... (6.2.4) "Reference conversions, implicit or explicit, never change the referential identity of the object being converted. In other words, while a reference conversion may change the type of the reference, it never changes the type or value of the object being referred to."